# How to get the value of a select drop down in javascript?

Tags: javascript

How can I alert the value selected by user from a select drop down box in Javascript. In this example I want to store the value inside a variable and alert it to the user.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function processmyform() {

    var chosenAnimal = // what goes here

    alert(chosenAnimal);

}
</script>

<form action="">
    <select name="animal" class="favAnimal">
        <option value="dog">Dog</option>
        <option value="cat">Cat</option>
        <option value="bird">Bird</option>
    </select>
    <a href="#" onclick="processmyform()" />
</form>
```

Comment: Are you using a JavaScript framework like jQuery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, it would be easier if your select box had an id.  Then you could use `getElementById`.

```
var animalSelectBox = document.getElementById('animal');
alert(animalSelectBox.options[animalSelectBox.selectedIndex].value);
```

Instead, here is how to do it using `getElementsByName` (notice this one is plural).

```
var arr = document.getElementsByName('animal'); //will be an array
alert(arr[0].options[arr[0].selectedIndex].value);
```

Comment: Be careful, though, getElementsByName has non-standard behavior in IE and Opera (gets elements that match name *or* id), and won't work on certain elements in IE. (See http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html)

Comment: Should work fine for this example though (although adding an id to the select would be preferable, as everyone seems to agree)

Answer (score 1):

I'd generally put an id on the select, like `id="animal"`

Then you could do:

```
var animal = document.getElementById("animal");
var animalValue = animal.options[animal.selectedIndex].value;
alert(animalValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would set an id on your select-tag:

```
<select id="animal" name="animal" class="favAnimal">
```

Javascript:

```
var chosenAnimal = document.getElementById("animal").value;
alert(chosenAnimal);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `selectedIndex`

```
<form id="yourForm" action="#">
    <select id="animal" name="animal" class="favAnimal">
        <option value="dog">Dog</option>
        <option value="cat">Cat</option>
        <option value="bird">Bird</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

window.onload = function(){
    var selectElement = document.getElementById('animal');

    document.getElementById('yourForm').onsubmit = function(){
        var index = selectElement.selectedIndex;
        alert(selectElement.options[index].value);
        alert(selectElement.options[index].text);
        alert(index);
        return false;
    };
};
```